# Unnest/explode a list/tuple containing uneven sublists

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list/tuple containing uneven sublists (query result from SQLAlchemy), which looks like this:

```
x = [('x', [1,2], [3,4])]
```

I want to unnest/explode `x` as the following:

```
x = [('x',[1],[3]),('x',[2],[4])]
```

Or

```
x = [('x',1,3),('x',2,4)]
```

I can achieve this using `pandas` dataframes with the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['X','A','B'])
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.explode() if x.name in ['A', 'B'] else x)
print([tuple(i) for i in df.values.tolist()])
```

which generates the following output:

```
[('x', 1, 3), ('x', 2, 4)]
```

However, I would love to know if there is any **pure python only** solution possible. I have been playing around with list comprehension based on following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) with no luck.

```
[item for sublist in x for item in sublist]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**:

my input looks like this:

```
[(u'x.x@gmail.com', u'Contact Info Refused/Not provided was Documented', 0L, 
[None, None, None], [1447748, 1447751, 1447750], 3L, [1491930], 'nce', 1, 2037)]
```

Expected output:

Just unpacking two sublist and keep everything the same.

```
[(u'x.x@gmail.com',u'Contact Info Refused/Not provided was Documented','0L',None,1447748,3L,[1491930],'nce',1,2037),
,(u'x.x@gmail.com',u'Contact Info Refused/Not provided was Documented','0L',None,1447751,3L,[1491930],'nce',1,2037),
(u'x.x@gmail.com',u'Contact Info Refused/Not provided was Documented','0L',None,1447750,3L,[1491930],'nce',1,2037))    ]
```

Comment: And what's the expected output?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am sorry to not add before. Added the expected output. I am interested in unpacking the sublists inside the tuple by keeping everything the same.

Comment: A list of tuples often works better as a dictionary. Is that something you'd consider?

Answer (score 1):

From `itertools`

```
import itertools
list(itertools.zip_longest(*x[0],fillvalue=x[0][0]))
Out[25]: [('x', 1, 3), ('x', 2, 4)]

# [list(itertools.zip_longest(*x[0],fillvalue=x[0][0])) for x in sublist]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works for the example. However, what if my input looks like this: `x = [('x', 'y', [1,2], [3,4])]`. I don't think it gives the right output.

Comment: @Grayrigel you may need to look at your real data and find the based format to write the special conversion